# react best way to set a loading

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

I'm using a `React.lazy` along with `Suspense` to set a loading.

```
const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => {
  const x = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(import("../Components/ListContainer"));
    }, 3000);
  });
  return x;
});

function Home() {
  return (
    <> 
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <LazyComponent />
      </Suspense> 
    </>
  );
}
```

In my code, I set the timeout to `3000`, but my objective is to make it loading until it completely fetched all the data and then renders all of the data at once.

Is there a way to achieve that? Or is there a better way to set a loading?

Comment: AFAIK Suspense should already handle that as long as the child has a React.lazy wrapped into it.

Comment: edited my post, the problem I'm facing is it will render and set the loading off and then render it one by one, but I expect it to render the data at once after the loading off.

Comment: _"...make it loading until it completely fetched all the data..."_ in order for this to be possible the data fetching itself needs to have suspense integration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle loading dynamically rather then give fix value of setTimeout.

**> Here are steps you do it:**

1- Create 3 actions for each network call: Like getDataPending, getDataSuccess, GetDataError

2- In getDataPending action put **loading=false**

3- In getDataSuccess action put **loading=true** and set **Error=false**

4- In getDataSuccess action put **loading=true** and set **Error=true**

5- Now call getDataPending right before network call

6- Call success action in getting response and Error action case of failure

This will help you to implement loading dynamically

**Happy Coading**